# Use extrenal dll in interface and a project

Tags: c#, dll

In my sln I have a project P1 which references a dll (managed)
In the dll some classes are defined, say class C1 and class C2.
I have other Interfaces project ,which defines interface. Besideds other it has an interface ,which P1 implements.
I need to write in interface the method which takes argument the class from dll .Should I add dlls to the references of interfaces project ?

Comment: Sounds to me you are about to create circular project references.  That cannot work.  You should strongly consider writing an interface instead so you can use it as the method argument.  If you have no control over the "external dll" then adding a reference to it in your interface project is appropriate and required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add dlls to interface project, because the clients that use interface must know the argument type. As an alternative, you could use type "object" as an argument type and then check the type on implementation side, but I would not recommend that.